# VBA Excel - cannot insert right data into loadfiles

Tags: excel, vba

I have an issue with creating .txt load files for SAP LSMW. The code takes data from an opened workbook and then populates various .txt files by various conditions - mostly by headers. The file worked well, but I would like to move data into two separate load files based on the data that is in the column under "BUKRS". Here comes an issue with Hlookup not being able to look for various values. Moreover, all of the data gets saved only to the file "05-Vend-Loadcache(No WHTAX).xls" I woudl like to divide the files by cost centre numbers that are in column "BUKRS". These are 9000, 5500, 6200, 8400, 8600, 8500. These ones should go to "06-Vend-Loadcache(WHTAX).xls". Unfortunately it does not work and only "05-Vend-Loadcache(No WHTAX).xls" gets populated. I have no clue why? Could you help me, please?

```
Sub VENDOR()
'CC3200 (LSMW1)  LNRZB (LSMW4) Line 60 for 5500 ....

CCD = Application.WorksheetFunction.HLookup("BUKRS", DTA.Range("A1:IV2"), 2, 0)
CCE = DTA.Cells(1, 60)
WFNA = "05-Vend-Loadcache(No WHTAX).xls"


Select Case CCD
Case 9000, 5500, 6200, 8400, 8600, 8500
WFNA = "06-Vend-Loadcache(WHTAX).xls"
End Select

SHT = "BISOVSH"
DATACHK = 1

If ((CCE = "" Or CCE = "CC3200" Or CCE = "VERKF" Or CCE = "TELF1" Or CCE = "KZRET") And WFNA = "05-Vend-Loadcache(No WHTAX).xls") Then
Call EXPORTDTA
Else
'do nothing as not to Export
 End If

If CCE = "LNRZB" And WFNA = "06-Vend-Loadcache(WHTAX).xls" Then
Call EXPORTDTA
Else
'do nothing as not to Export
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you show an example of your first data line only within a loop? In any case plz (1) Could you add some example data to your question by *editing your OP* (especially in column XY containing "BUKRS" and cell BH1 (`cells(1,60)`)? (2) Do you export your data row wise? - if not, you would have to edit the `ExportData` code, too. (3) Did you declare variables in the declaration head of your code module (or public) or in the cited Sub VENDOR (assume you use `Option Explicit`)? (4) Please edit occuring error messages of your code so far.

Comment: BTW: when using `Application.WorksheetFunction.HLookup`, it's necessary that you always find a column containing "BUKRS", otherwise you'll have to provide by error trapping. (the alternative `Application.HLookup` function would require a somewhat different approach via `IsError`)

Comment: The whole issue was actually related to the macros that I called from the procedures. Thank you TM nonetheless!